# spark master goes down with out of memory exception

Tags: apache-spark

I have 1 spark master and 2 slave nodes setup with 8 gb memory each on AWS. I have setup spark master to run every 1 hour. I have a cassandra database which is read every hour from spark to get records and process it in spark. There are around 5000 records every hour. My spark master crashed in one of the run saying

```
"15/12/20 11:04:45 ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkMaster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4436] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkMaster]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at scala.math.BigInt$.apply(BigInt.scala:82)
        at org.json4s.jackson.JValueDeserializer.deserialize(JValueDeserializer.scala:16)
        at org.json4s.jackson.JValueDeserializer.deserialize(JValueDeserializer.scala:42)
        at org.json4s.jackson.JValueDeserializer.deserialize(JValueDeserializer.scala:35)
        at org.json4s.jackson.JValueDeserializer.deserialize(JValueDeserializer.scala:42)
        at org.json4s.jackson.JValueDeserializer.deserialize(JValueDeserializer.scala:35)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3066)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2161)
        at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$class.parse(JsonMethods.scala:19)
        at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(JsonMethods.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus.replay(ReplayListenerBus.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.rebuildSparkUI(Master.scala:793)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.removeApplication(Master.scala:734)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.org$apache$spark$deploy$master$Master$$finishApplication(Master.scala:712)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$28.apply(Master.scala:445)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$28.apply(Master.scala:445)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1.applyOrElse(Master.scala:445)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
        at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.aroundReceive(Master.scala:52)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
"
```

Can you please let me know the reason why spark master crashed with out of memory. I have this as setup for spark
_executorMemory=6G
_driverMemory=6G
creating 8 paritions in my code.
Why does master goes down which out of memory

Here is the code

```
//create spark context
_sparkContext = new SparkContext(_conf)

//load the cassandra table
val tabledf = _sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "events", "keyspace" -> "sams")).load

        val whereQuery = "addedtime >= '" + _from + "' AND addedtime < '" + _to + "'"
        helpers.printnextLine("Where query to run on Cassandra : " + whereQuery)
        val rdd = tabledf.filter(whereQuery)

        rdd.registerTempTable("rdd")

        val selectQuery = "lower(brandname) as brandname, lower(appname) as appname, lower(packname) as packname, lower(assetname) as assetname, eventtime, lower(eventname) as eventname, lower(client.OSName) as platform, lower(eventorigin) as eventorigin, meta.price as price"
        val modefiedDF = _sqlContext.sql("select " + selectQuery + " from rdd")

        //cache the rdd
        modefiedDF.cache


// perform groupby operation
grprdd = filterrdd.groupBy("brandname", "appname", "packname", "eventname", "platform", "eventorigin", "price").count()

grprdd.foreachPartition{iter => 
            {

iter.foreach(element =>
                        {

// Write to sql server table
val statement = con.createStatement()
                                statement.executeUpdate(insertQuery)
finally
                    {
                        if(con != null)
                            con.close
                    }

// clear the cache 
_sqlContext.clearCache()
```

Comment: Is there any other application running on the same host as spark-master which is using all available memory?

Comment: No there is no other application. Only spark is setup on this 8 gb ram machine from AWS

Comment: Also what is observed was it completed running my job and then after my job got completed it went down

Comment: Can you paste some code? Are you using spark streaming?

Comment: Updated with some snippet code.

Comment: How are you doing the scheduling? via Oozie/Cron or by While Loop?

Comment: its a cronjob. Its run after every 1 hour

Comment: Any luck in solving the issue? I see similar problems when at same method gets involved: `org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.rebuildSparkUI(Master.scala:793)`

Comment: No i could not find the issue. There were no memory leaks in the code. I had to start the spark master with start-all script before running my job. In case my spark crashes, it will be run with the start-all script

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you are asking spark master to use 6 GB and spark executor to use another 6 GB (total 12  GB to be used). However the system only has a total 8 GB RAM available.

Of this 8 GB you should also allow some memory to be utilized for OS processes (say 1 GB)k. Thus total RAM available to spark (master and worker combined) is only 7 GB.
Set `executorMemory` and `driverMemory` accordingly.

Comment: My worker or slaves are on different machine each with 8 gb ram. Also my job ran successfully. Its after the completion of the job that the master went down

Comment: Since my job runs every hour its just that after 2-3 days i saw this exception

Comment: @Nipun Seeing exactly the same issue for spark 1.4.1. Manifest every 2-3 days after all jobs are done (not while executing).

Comment: @marios : as a workaround i have added start-all in mu script to start spark in case it went down

Comment: I think this is the best way to handle this at the moment. I am wondering if it was solved in later version. Are you also seeing this on 1.4.1?